# configParams undefined in getData() call

Tags: looker-studio

I'm in the process of building a community connector and am scratching my head; the documentation states:

> getData()
>
> Returns the tabular data for the given request.
>
> Request
>
> @param {Object} request A JavaScript object containing the data
>   request parameters.
>
> The request parameter contains user provided values and additional
>   information that can be used to complete the data request. It has the
>   following structure:
>
> {   "configParams": object,   "scriptParams": {
>       "sampleExtraction": boolean,
>       "lastRefresh": string   },   "dateRange": {
>       "startDate": string,
>       "endDate": string   },   "fields": [
>       {
>         object(Field)
>       }   ] }

I've correctly setup getConfig() (at least, my configurations are requested from the user), but my getData function is not being passed a configParams object. Here's my code.

```
function getConfig(request) {

  var Harvest = HarvestService({
    token: getHarvestAuthService().getAccessToken()
  });
  var accounts = Harvest.accounts.list();
  var options = accounts.map(function(account) {

    return {
      label: account.name,
      value: account.id
    };

  });

  var config = {
    configParams: [
      {
        type: 'SELECT_SINGLE',
        name: 'harvestAccountId',
        displayName: 'Harvest Account ID',
        helpText: 'The ID of the Harvest Account to pull data from.',
        options: options
      }
    ],
    dateRangeRequired: true
  };

  return config;

}

function getData(request) {

  var startDate = request.dateRange.startDate;
  var endDate = request.dateRange.endDate;
  var accountId = request.configParams.harvestAccountId;
  var harvestAuthService = getHarvestAuthService();

  var Harvest = HarvestService({
    token: harvestAuthService.getAccessToken(),
    account: accountId
  });

  var fieldKeys = request.fields.map(function(field) { return field.name; });

  var entries = Harvest.entries.list({
    startDate: new Date(startDate),
    endDate: new Date(endDate)
  });

  var rows = entries.map(entryToRow);

  return {
    schema: request.fields,
    rows: rows,
    cachedData: false
  };

}
```

When I test/debug, I can select an Account at the config step, the schema is correctly returned, but I get the following exception when I try and add a widget to the report:

> Script error message: 
>   TypeError: Cannot read property "harvestAccountId" from undefined.
>   Script error cause: USER  Script
>   error stacktrace:    getData:244

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem - the issue was that the value attribute of the option was a number, but it MUST be a string:

https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getconfig

Leaving this here in case anyone else gets stuck on this. Your config select options for your Data Studio Community Connector must have strings for both the label and the value, and nobody will coerce them for you. Fix was this:

```
var options = accounts.map(function(account) {

  return {
    label: account.name,
    value: account.id + ''
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `request.configParams` is `undefined` when there are no configuration values passed from the user config.

1. When testing the connector, are you selecting a value in the dropdown for `harvestAccountId`?
2. If you plan to share this connector with other users, it might be a good idea to have a default value for `harvestAccountId` in case the user does not select an option.
3. You can use [Apps Script logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) to see the response for `getConfig()` to ensure that right values are getting passed for options. Then you can also log the `request` for `getData()` to have a better understanding of what exactly is getting passed in the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; the issue was my values weren't strings and they aren't coerced behind the scenes.

Comment: Hey, some of our connector's users reported a problem. I checked the logs it turned out that for some reason `configParams` is `undefined` in `getData` request. 
I verified all of your suggestions - `getConfig` response looks fine, all config params are strings.

User reported that it happens daily and the only thing that helps is updating the data source:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5732023/56412982-3b354f80-6286-11e9-9bc6-c97d87ea3821.png

I asked them to share the report with me, but I it didn't break for me. Do you have any other ideas what can be a reason?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this in case it helps anyone, note that the config params in the UI although they have a placeholder value need to be physically populated to appear in the request. Indeed, if none of these are filled in the `configParams` value does not appear in the `request` object.